# Wordpress Walker — how to add number of post to category menu items?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I wanted to add number of posts for menu items that are categories.
For example:

1. Category 1 (5)
2. Category 2 (8)
3. Category 3 (2)

etc...

I edit **walker**:

*get number:*

```
$item_count = $depth == 0 ? get_posts( array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'orderby' => 'category',
  'order' => 'ASC'
) ) : false;
```

*output:*

```
$item_output .= $item_count ? ' <span>(' . count( $item_count ) . ')</span>' : '';
```

The result is a postscript to each menu item the number of all posts.
**How to modify?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [wp_list_categories](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

```
<?php wp_list_categories(array('show_count' => true)); ?>
```

**UPDATE for your instance:**

with the full code from the [link you provided in the comments](http://illuminatikarate.com/blog/bootstrap-walker-for-wordpress/) we add an if statement right before the closing `<a>`

```
if($item->type == 'taxonomy'){
                $cat = get_category( $item->object_id);
                $item_output .= ' ('.$cat->count.')</a>';
            }
```

FULL CODE:

```
/* Bootstrap_Walker for Wordpress
     * Author: George Huger, Illuminati Karate, Inc
     * More Info: http://illuminatikarate.com/blog/bootstrap-walker-for-wordpress
     *
     * Formats a Wordpress menu to be used as a Bootstrap dropdown menu (http://getbootstrap.com).
     *
     * Specifically, it makes these changes to the normal Wordpress menu output to support Bootstrap:
     *
     *      - adds a 'dropdown' class to level-0 <li>'s which contain a dropdown
     *       - adds a 'dropdown-submenu' class to level-1 <li>'s which contain a dropdown
     *       - adds the 'dropdown-menu' class to level-1 and level-2 <ul>'s
     *
     * Supports menus up to 3 levels deep.
     *
     */
    class Bootstrap_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
    {

        /* Start of the <ul>
         *
         * Note on $depth: Counterintuitively, $depth here means the "depth right before we start this menu".
         *                 So basically add one to what you'd expect it to be
         */
        function start_lvl(&$output, $depth)
        {
            $tabs = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            // If we are about to start the first submenu, we need to give it a dropdown-menu class
            if ($depth == 0 || $depth == 1) { //really, level-1 or level-2, because $depth is misleading here (see note above)
                $output .= "\n{$tabs}<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n";
            } else {
                $output .= "\n{$tabs}<ul>\n";
            }
            return;
        }

        /* End of the <ul>
         *
         * Note on $depth: Counterintuitively, $depth here means the "depth right before we start this menu".
         *                 So basically add one to what you'd expect it to be
         */
        function end_lvl(&$output, $depth)
        {
            if ($depth == 0) { // This is actually the end of the level-1 submenu ($depth is misleading here too!)

                // we don't have anything special for Bootstrap, so we'll just leave an HTML comment for now
                $output .= '<!--.dropdown-->';
            }
            $tabs = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "\n{$tabs}</ul>\n";
            return;
        }

        /* Output the <li> and the containing <a>
         * Note: $depth is "correct" at this level
         */
        function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
        {
            global $wp_query;
            $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
            $class_names = $value = '';
            $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

            /* If this item has a dropdown menu, add the 'dropdown' class for Bootstrap */
            if ($item->hasChildren) {
                $classes[] = 'dropdown';
                // level-1 menus also need the 'dropdown-submenu' class
                if($depth == 1) {
                    $classes[] = 'dropdown-submenu';
                }
            }

            /* This is the stock Wordpress code that builds the <li> with all of its attributes */
            $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
            $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';
            $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';
            $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )  ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'  . esc_attr( $item->xfn      ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
            $item_output = $args->before;

            /* If this item has a dropdown menu, make clicking on this link toggle it */
            if ($item->hasChildren && $depth == 0) {
                $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">';
            } else {
                $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
            }

            $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;

            /* Output the actual caret for the user to click on to toggle the menu */
            if ($item->hasChildren && $depth == 0) {
                $item_output .= '<b class="caret"></b></a>';
            }elseif($item->type == 'taxonomy'){
                $cat = get_category( $item->object_id);
                $item_output .= ' ('.$cat->count.')</a>';
            } else {
                $item_output .= '</a>';
            }

            $item_output .= $args->after;
            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
            return;
        }

        /* Close the <li>
         * Note: the <a> is already closed
         * Note 2: $depth is "correct" at this level
         */
        function end_el (&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
        {
            $output .= '</li>';
            return;
        }

        /* Add a 'hasChildren' property to the item
         * Code from: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-know-if-a-menu-item-has-children-or-is-a-leaf#post-3139633
         */
        function display_element ($element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output)
        {
            // check whether this item has children, and set $item->hasChildren accordingly
            $element->hasChildren = isset($children_elements[$element->ID]) && !empty($children_elements[$element->ID]);

            // continue with normal behavior
            return parent::display_element($element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! how can I include wp_list_categories in wp_nav_menu => walker ?

Comment: how are you getting the categories now in the menu? through the admin?

Comment: yes through the admin. I registered 1 menu and connected [Bootstrap_Walker](http://illuminatikarate.com/blog/bootstrap-walker-for-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some custom post taxonomie you can change the code for this one :

```
if ($item->type == 'taxonomy'){
    $term = get_term($item->object_id); 
    $item_output .= '<div class="meni-item-badge"> '.$term->count .'</div>'; 
}
```

Hope this help someone !!
Regards Mario